# pointCloud2 to pointCloud

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I am using the pointcloud assembler in the laser_assembler package, unfortunately the package can only assemble pointclouds which are pointcloud1

The kinect i am using only publishes pointcloud2

Does anyone know how to convert pointCloud2 into pointcloud?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64000/pointcloud2-to-pointcloud/) by [Sentinal_Bias](https://answers.ros.org/users/4120/sentinal_bias/) on ROS Answers with karma: 418 on 2013-05-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use this http://www.ros.org/wiki/point_cloud_converter

You could look at the source to see if there's any change needed for Fuerte or Groovy (probably not, since it's mostly data copying)

See also http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl/Overview#Converting_between_the_.60sensor_msgs::PointCloud.60_and_.60sensor_msgs::PointCloud2.60_format

---

Originally posted by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) with karma: 2268 on 2013-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sentinal_Bias](https://answers.ros.org/users/4120/sentinal_bias/) on 2013-05-30**:
Hi i found  the package sensor_msg http://ros.org/wiki/sensor_msgs there is a fuction in the code api which does pointcloud conversion, but i am not sure how to access the static function http://www.ros.org/doc/api/sensor_msgs/html/namespacesensor__msgs.html#ab3bdbe5a82173d3483899c776e6ccbab i

**Comment by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) on 2013-05-30**:
You can always search for the function and see if others have used it. And follow how it is done. I would suggest using the point_cloud_converter node instead if you don't really need to know the nitty gritty.

**Comment by [Sentinal_Bias](https://answers.ros.org/users/4120/sentinal_bias/) on 2013-05-30**:
Hi thanks the pointcloud converter works in fuerte no build errors